# Live editing of RGB values in rgba

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm building a site where I want users to be able to change the color of one of the divs. The color is set with rgba because i want it to be transparent.

The problem I'm having, is I have found a color picker, but i change change the RGB without screwing up the opacity. Here's how I have it so far:

```
<input class="color" type="text" onchange="document.getElementById('main-info').style.backgroundColor = '#' + this.color;">
```

Obviously I'm replacing the rgba for with hex for the live version, which kills the opacity. The other things I've tried is:

```
<input class="color" type="text" onchange=" document.getElementById('id_info_box_bg_color').value = (Math.floor(this.color.rgb[0]*255)) + ', ' + (Math.floor(this.color.rgb[1]*255)) + ', ' + (Math.floor(this.color.rgb[2]*255));">
```

which successfully gets the rgba values, but i can't get it to insert properly into the rgba.

Anyone know how i can replace part of the rgba?  So I'm just changing the Xs in rgba(X, X, X, .5)

Comment: that's the color value the color picker outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can replace just part of the rgba value, but if the color of the div is set with rgba in css, you can retrieve the rgba string value by asking for the css property:

```
$('#myDiv').css('background-color');
```

This will return a string that looks like this (for example): "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.496094)" or, if the opacity was set to 1, "rgb(255, 0, 0)" From this you could parse out the alpha channel value and use it when you set the new rgba value. I'm sure there's someone smarter than me that could find an efficient way of extracting that value from the string(or at least not as lazy as me.) When you want to set the new color for the div:

```
$('#myDiv').css('background-color', 'newColor');
```

where new color is a string you construct in the same form as when you set it in css or retrieve it subsequently as I showed above, using the same alpha value extracted from the original string.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to get the same net effect with css

```
#id_info_box_bg_color {
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // ms ie 8 first!
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);                    // rest of the ie browsers second!
  opacity: .5;  // standard compliant browsers
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, opacity wont work for me here. That makes a container and all it's children lighter, not just the background. At least that's what I understand.